# Rewrite flat url to parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I read quite a lot of posts on this, but nothing I could make work (or understand) so far. Let me apologize beforehand for asking something that might seems already answered.

I have personalized URLs ( fx. http://www.somedomain.com/someword ) which I need to turn into http://www.somedomain.com/test.php?name=someword

The parameter (someword) is based on a persons name, meaning there's no file-ending (like .html)

I tried a number of rewrites with htaccess, but no matter what, I get 'Internal server error', for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^(.+)$   test.php?name=$1   [L]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Hans

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is looping since `.+` matches URI after rewriting also.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.+)$   test.php?name=$1 [L]
```